# MATLAB: How to calculate the accumulated return

Tags: matlab

This is what the data looks like:

> 'Return'
>
> 10%
>
> -30%
>
> 0
>
> 2.3%
>
> ....

How to calculate accumulated return which equals '(1+10%)(1-30%)(1+0)(1+2.3%)(1+...)(1+...)...'

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have some kind of an array, which looks as below. Then the following bit of code would work.

```
ret=[10 -30 0 2.3];
output=prod(1+ret/100)
```

The key is the prod function, which will multiply all values in the vector. Also, remember that `return` is a keyword, and can't be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like homework. Here are the pieces you'll need.

- Read line-by-line from a file via [fgets](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fgets.html).
- For each line, remove the % sign via logical indexing. i.e., line_in(1:end-1)
- Convert the percentage to a decimal. i.e., 30% -> 0.3
- Use a forloop to accumulate that lines 1+